# Caret-dot-dot notaion in GIT

Tags: git

What does the following git syntax mean: `6df7640^..`
I've seen it there: http://git-scm.com/book/ca/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery

I've looked for this syntax description in http://schacon.github.io/git/git-rev-parse.html but didn't find an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The caret means previous version. `..` signifies "from-to", omitting the "to" part just takes HEAD.

So `6df7640^..` means from the parent commit of `6df7640` to `HEAD`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit more involved than `blackbuild` stated.  The [gitrevisions(7)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) manual has it all but it's language is somewhat dry to let's try to elaborate.

### The caret

The caret, `^`, actually means the first parent of a commit it follows.

The idea is that merge commits have more than one parent (Git even supports the so-called "octopus" merges, where more than one branches are merged into another so that the resulting merge commit has more than *two* parents).

You'd use `^2` if you'd want to select the second parent (what was merged), `^3` for the third and so on.

### The `..` range operator

The `A..B` notation is, again, does not mean something as simple as "from A to B". The manual defines it as

> `<rev1>..<rev2>`
>
> Include commits that are reachable from `<rev2>` but exclude those that are reachable from `<rev1>`.

…and slightly above that

> `^<rev>`
>
> Exclude commits that are reachable from (i.e. ancestors of) .

As you can see, neither "from" nor "to" are mentioned.

That's because Git history is a directed acyclic graph, not just a timeline of commits, and hence Git history traversal commands (which accept such ranges) operate on *sets of commits,* not timelines. Now here comes the notion of "commit reachability": if you point at an arbitrary commit on a history graph of your repository, you might move from there down chasing the parent commit(s) of that commit, their parent commit(s) and so on and so on.  Hence, given a single commit on a history's DAG, you can get a subgraph of all the commits *reachable* from that one.  Logically, all those commits form the state of the code base maintained by that "anchor" commit.

Now if you want to *limit* the set of commits which form a subgraph, say, for history inspection purpose, you have to *prune* uninteresting parts of that subgraph.  This is precisely what's done by that *prefix* `^` exclusion operator mentioned above.

Hence `<rev1>..<rev2>` is another form of `<rev2> ^<rev1>` for Subversion refugees. What makes the second, more generic, form interesting is that while for a simple case like

```
...-A-B-C-D-E-F
```

both forms, `B..E` and `E ^B` produce exactly the same results, for a more complicated case like

```
...-X-Y-Z
         \
...-A-B-C-D-E-F
        /
 ...-U-W
```

(with `C` and `D` being merge commits) they will produce different results as `B..E` won't prune the subgraphs anchored at `Z` and `W`, and if you'd like to prune them as well, you'd use `E ^B ^Z ^W` — something the "two-dot" form can't do.

#### The `..` range operator and `git diff`

Another thing which is useful to keep in mind is that for `git diff`, the `..` operator means different thing than for history traversing commands like `git log`.  This is a subtle difference, especially if one uses something like `<rev>^` on the left side of `..`.

The difference is that `git diff` always considers only two revisions: for `A..B` it considers only `A` and `B` and does not care what commits are between them, how `A` and `B` are topologically related and even if they're related at all (one is reachable from another).

So it's better to always use just two separate revision arguments when working with `git diff`, like `git diff A B` to compare `A` to `B`.